# unable to send data to api

Tags: javascript, android, api, react-native

i have a function that sends some data to an api, and api should return the same data i've sent. the function in react-native is this:

```
async CheckUserLoginFromApi(apiToken) {
    try {

        let response = await
            fetch('http://10.0.2.2/arjin/api/v1/checkAPIToken/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                   apiToken
                })
            });

        let json = await response.json();

        console.log(json);

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

}
```

and the function in api is this:

```
public function checkAPIToken()
{
    wp_send_json($_POST);
}
```

but the api returns an empty array. what is the problem?

Comment: api is written in which language ?anyway your api method seems like parameterless, it should accept a parameter type of your apiToken probably string

Comment: where do you call `checkAPIToken` method?

Comment: php in wordpress, when i send the same data from postman in chrome, it works properly

Comment: i call the function in componentWillMount

Comment: ok, where you call `componentWillMount`?And what is this `componentWillMount`? I think that you just don't send data in some cases, but it is totally unclear when.

Comment: componentWillMount is a function in react native which runs before render. it s a default function, and always run when you start the app